# How to create a dynamic factory in Symfony2

Tags: symfony, dependency-injection, factory

In most cases I use services and take advantage of the service container. However, one of my classes, let's call it MyClass, has some dependencies which are created dynamically according to a parameter which is knows only at the runtime. For example, if the parameter is 'A', it should create MyClass with the dependencies of Connection, Logger, Dep1A, Dep2A, Dep3A. If the parameter is B, it should be Connection, Logger, Dep1B, Dep2B, Dep3B.

I understand that it is not possible in Symfony to create a service with dynamic parameters that are knows only after the container is built. From a quick search, I've found that the classic solution is to do setter injections for those 3 dynamic dependencies. The problem is that I need to use MyClass in many places, and it doesn't make sense to create every time each one of these 3 dependencies.

I would say that creating a factory: MyClassFactory which get a string parameter and return MyClass accordingly, should be the solution. However, things are getting complicated in Symfony, where the Logger and Connection are services, and I can't inject them automatically into the Factory because again, I can't create the Factory as a service due to the dynamic parameter.

If you have any idea how to tackle this, I would love to read.

**Edit1:** an example of my situation - I've a big system and I'm now integrating with a Search Engine. My entities are, say, Blog, Post, User. I would like to index them in the search-engine storage, check the index status, search them, etc. In this example, MyClass is actually SearchIntegration

```
interface EntityConfigInterface {
    public function getConfig();
}

class PostConfig implements EntityConfigInterface {
    public function getConfig(){}
}
class UserConfig implements EntityConfigInterface {
    public function getConfig(){}
}

interface EntityIndexInterface {
    public function getRecordsToIndex();
    public function countRecords();
}
class PostIndex implements EntityIndexInterface {
    public function getRecordsToIndex(){}
    public function countRecords(){}
}
class UserIndex implements EntityIndexInterface {
    public function getRecordsToIndex(){}
    public function countRecords(){}
}

class SearchIntegration {
    public function __construct(Connection $connection, Logger $logger, $externalSearchEngine, EntityConfigInterface $config, EntityIndexInterface $index) {

    }

    public function checkStatusIndex($entityName) {
        return $this->index->countRecords() === $this->externalSearchEngine->countRecords($entityName);
    }
}

class SearchIntegrationFactory {
    public static function build($entity) {
        switch ($entity) {
            case 'post':
                return new SearchIntegration(new Connection, new Logger, new ExternalSearchEngine, new PostConfig, new PostIndex);
            case 'user':
                return new SearchIntegration(new Connection, new Logger, new ExternalSearchEngine, new UserConfig, new userIndex);
        }

    }
}

Class SearchIntegrationController {
    public function checkIndexStatusForAllEntities() {
        //HOW TO GET THE INSTANCE OF SearchIntegrationFactory::build('user')?
        $userSearchIntegration = $this->get('search_integration'); 
        $userStatus = $userSearchIntegration->checkStatusIndex();

        //HOW TO GET THE INSTANCE OF SearchIntegrationFactory::build('post')?
        $postSearchIntegration = $this->get('search_integration'); 
        $postStatus = $postSearchIntegration->checkStatusIndex();

        echo $userStatus, $postStatus;
    }
}
```

**Edit2: The final factory class** according to @John Noel Solution with some adjustments:

Config.yml

```
search_integration_factory:
    class: SearchIntegrationFactory
    arguments:
           [@service_container]
```

SearchIntegrationFactory Class:

```
class SearchIntegrationFactory {

    private $container;

    public function __construct(Container $container) {
        $this->container = $container;
    }

    public function build($entity) {
        $entityConfig = $this->container->get($entity . '_config');
        $entityIndex = $this->container->get($entity . '_index');

        return new SearchIntegration(
            $this->container->get('Connection'),
            $this->container->get('logger'),
            new ExternalSearchEngine,
            $entityConfig,
            $entityIndex
        );
    }
}
```

And then to build the class:

```
$this->get('search_integration_factory')->build('post');
$this->get('search_integration_factory')->build('user');
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Edit:** So based upon what you've said above, it sounds like you just need to setup your `SearchIntergrationFactory` as a standard service, then within your code grab it and call your "build" function as usual rather than trying to do it from the DI container. E.g.

```
searchintegrationfactory:
    class: SearchIntegrationFactory
    calls:
        - [ setLogger, [ @logger ] ]
```

Then in your `SearchIntegrationController`:

```
// note, your factory shouldn't use a static method here
$userSearchIntegration = $this->get('searchintegrationfactory')->build($entity);
```

This is almost identical to how Doctrine does its entity management, in that every time you want a repository, you do:

```
$this->get('doctrine')->getManager()->getRepository('Entity:Page');
```

Is there something preventing you from doing it this way?

--

It sounds like you probably want to look at using the factory capabilities of the Symfony service container ([documentation](http://symfony.com/doc/current/components/dependency_injection/factories.html)).

From your description, your other classes only want to know about `MyClass`. In which case your container description might look something like:

```
myclass.factory:
    class: MyClassFactory
    arguments:
        - @connection
        - @logger

myclass:
    class: MyClass # as per documentation, this isn't actually used
    factory: [ @myclass.factory, "getMyClass" ]
    arguments:
        - %runtime_parameter% # if you can parameterise
        - @service.to.get.runtime_parameter # if you can't
```

Now this doesn't handle your other dependencies (`Dep1A` etc.) which, depending on what they are will guide how you solve this problem. You can either pass the container as a parameter to your factory and just `get()` the dependencies you need during `MyClass` creation, or you can pass all of the dependencies you need to the factory and be done with it.

Both have their drawbacks, the former breaks the "minimum surface area" maxim for service descriptions while the latter might be untenable if you have a lot of dependencies.

Without knowing more about the set up it sounds like something, somewhere might need refactoring or rearchitecting so that this situation doesn't arise but that's outside the scope of solving this particular issue.

Comment: I understand, but I think I'm missing something here, let's say that I'm going with the option of passing the entire container to the factory. In order for the factory to create MyClass it needs the runtime parameter, how do I pass it to the factory? I see that you mentioned in the config.yml `myclass: "%runtime_parameter%"`, however, it's not possible to create the runtime_parameter after the container is built. Imagine that I need to create MyClass twice at the same http-request, first time with 'A', second time with 'B'. How this is possible?

Comment: So the question is where is your "runtime" parameter coming from? Is it coming from the request object, your server environment etc? Wherever it's coming from you have a way of retrieving it - be that checking the request or examining the environment - in which case you build a service to retrieve that parameter and pass that service to the factory. Thats the `@service.to.get.runtime_parameter` part of my answer above. If you can be more specific about this "runtime" parameter that would help.

Comment: I've edited my question and added an example, as you can see in that example, sometimes I need to instantiate SearchIntegration multiple times in the same request, so I need to pass the parameter of my entity to the factory in the runtime. That's what I'm missing - how to pass this parameter to the Factory. Please let me know if it's not clear. Thanks!

Comment: I've updated my answer above to try and match the new information.

Comment: That's great, I think we have a solution. In reality in the build() method I can't do `new PostConfig` as PostConfig has some dependencies such as db connection, so I need to inject this service into the 'searchintegrationfactory' service. The problem is that the service to inject is depends on the entity parameter I pass to build(). However, as you mentioned I can pass the entire container and then fetch the correct service according to the entity. I've updated the question with the final solution based on your input. Thanks a lot!